# When trying to convert an SSH file, I got this error: Couldn't load private key (SSH-2 public key (OpenSSH format))

Tags: ssh, putty, rsa, dsa

I have downloaded an SSH RSA key .pub file, and I have attempted it to convert it in the PuTTY Key Generator. However, I have had problems with converting it due to an error loading the key. The error I got while trying to convert it was: Couldn't load private key (SSH-2 public key (OpenSSH format)). I need to use SSH for command typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the private key. You can't use the public key to compute a private key, that is the whole point of private/public key cryptography.

Get the file without the `.pub` extension.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I already converted the private key.